# Infopath Data Conections from code behind

Tags: 2013, infopath, query, data

I have a form in infopath 2013, I am getting data from a sharepoint list to perform some actions, but I need the data query of the data to be done when I press the button on my form.

I have code in the click event of the button that performs other validations and try to add a rule to the control of the button to make the query with the data, but it doesnt work, because the button has code. It is possible to perform data query with code from the click event of the button.